# Pagination without query number of pages?

Tags: pagination

How can I do a pagination system without query number of elements and without getting all elements from db. I want to use a dynamic size or an iterator. I want to avoid  SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS or COUNT(*).

Comment: What kind of pagination? with page numbers?

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel Yes, with page numbers

Comment: How it is supposed to get the number of pages without knowing the number of records?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using MySQL, [SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS](http://www.michikono.com/2007/08/07/the-secret-of-sql_calc_found_rows/) followed by `SELECT FOUND_ROWS()` is your friend. Otherwise, you must do a separate `COUNT(*)` query in order to find out how much data is available.

Either way, once you know how many rows there are, you can divide by the items per page to count the pages and sort out the pagination controls. It's not really hard. The overhead of counting the data (provided that one asks the database to count it instead of retrieving it all and counting manually) is not that much.

Alternatively, a lot of sites these days get lazy and resort to crude "Load more items" buttons instead of real pagination. If you hate your users or it's not more than a few pages then that's a good option.

Answer (score 0):

Well, without knowing how many items there are, you cannot create a full pagination interface. You can show the user "next"/"previous" buttons but you cannot show them how many pages there are, or what page they're currently on.

And... that's all I can say about it, because you gave zero detail.